# How to run unitest from different directories with Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following structure in my project;

```
project
    src
    ├── A.py
    └── B.py
    tests
    ├── test_b.py
```

and in B.py I import A.py like this;

```
from A import foo
```

B.py works fine when I run it.
However when testing B.py in test_b.py I get an error saying

```
No module named A
```

I can make the test work with relative imports in B.py, but that fails when I run the module by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative imports outside packages is a recipe for nightmares. Everything forks fine when you develop and test in the source directory. And problems start to occur as soon as you want to use your code from a different directory.

The workaround: Consistently add the directory of `__file__` in `sys.path` before your local imports. As `sys.path` is a writable list, it will work. You should at least try to not add the directory if it is already present...

The idiomatic way: If you need local imports, then you probably need a package. It may require some work, because packages are expected to be *installed*, but it is a large + if you intend to later deploy your code. The downside, it that a package must be started as a module (`python -m x.y`) and not as a plain script (`python x/y.py`). With your current structure, I would just add an empty `__init__.py` file in both `src` and `tests` folder, and add a `__main__.py` file in src if you want to lauch directly the package.

Then you should run everything (including tests and dev runs) from project: `python -m src.B [params...]`. Same thing for the tests `python -m tests.test_b`. Or directly (as the test folder and files start with test): `python -m unittest discover`

Comment: This worked great, but what would the best practice be when it comes to testing?